# Why do I not get a p-value from this ANOVA in R?

Tags: r, anova, dataset, degrees-of-freedom

Here's the data:

```
> tires <- data.frame(Wear  = c(17, 14, 12, 13, 14, 14, 12, 11,
                                13, 13, 10, 11, 13, 8, 9, 9),
                      Brand = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 4),
                      Car   = as.character(as.roman(rep(1:4, each = 4))))
> tires
   Wear Brand Car
1    17     A   I
2    14     B   I
3    12     C   I
4    13     D   I
5    14     A  II
6    14     B  II
7    12     C  II
8    11     D  II
9    13     A III
10   13     B III
11   10     C III
12   11     D III
13   13     A  IV
14    8     B  IV
15    9     C  IV
16    9     D  IV
```

Now I fit a two-way ANOVA with interaction:

```
two.way <- aov(Wear ~ Brand + Car + Brand:Car, data = tires)
```

Finally, no p-values:

```
> summary(two.way)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
Brand        3  30.69  10.229
Car          3  38.69  12.896
Brand:Car    9  11.56   1.285
```

A regular two-way ANOVA (i.e., `Wear ~ Brand + Car`) gives me p-values:

```
> summary(aov(Wear ~ Brand + Car, data = tires))
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
Brand        3  30.69  10.229   7.962 0.00668 **
Car          3  38.69  12.896  10.038 0.00313 **
Residuals    9  11.56   1.285                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Is there a way to interpret this? The interaction plot shows me that there is definitely interaction between `Brand` and `Car` so I am hoping to incorporate this into my model.

Answer (score 18):

Your model is saturated.  Any model will use at least 1 degree of freedom.  You have 2 factors with 4 levels each.  They both require 3 additional degrees of freedom.  The interaction consumes another 9 degrees of freedom.  Summing those 1 + 3 + 3 + 9 = 16, but you have only 16 data.  Thus, there are no degrees of freedom left with which to determine the residual variability, form standard errors, or test any hypotheses.

Comment: Thank you. Since there is a clear interaction effect here, is there any alternative analysis I can perform or am I limited to the two-way ANOVA without interaction in this case?

Comment: There is no way possible that it can be "clear" there is an interaction effect. I don't doubt that you interpret what you see as an interaction, but it is logically not possible to determine whether there is an interaction. You need more data. A lot more.

Comment: Not sure I totally agree with you @gung. Though it's rather philosophical, I think you can have a clear interaction effect based on point estimates alone, though you will lack the ability to statistically test it.

Comment: @wanny This is not a "philosophical issue." Gung is absolutely correct here: without at least *one* additional data value, there is no information about variability in the saturated model. The impression of an interaction can *always* be created in this situation simply by sorting the columns and rows appropriately: that makes such an impression merely an artifact of how one has presented the data. OTOH, if the names of brands (A,B,C,D) and cars (I,II,III,IV) had some natural or meaningful order (e.g., related to market share or price), then an interaction *could* be tested with these data.

Comment: Agreed, I was assuming the factors were ordered.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to propose an alternative in case anyone comes with the same doubt.

As it was stated previously, in the design of your model we couldn´t consider a posible interaction $\gamma_{ij}$ between the factors brand and car:

$$
y_{ij}=\mu+ \alpha_i+\beta_j+ \gamma_{ij}+\epsilon_{ij}
$$

specially because we lack observations to make an stimation of the parameters, so the model is saturated. However, we could propose  a test with a degree of freedom as follows:

$$
y_{ij}=\mu+ \alpha_i+\beta_j+ \lambda(\hat\alpha_i\hat\beta_j)+\epsilon_{ij}
$$

where the interaction is simplified as the product of the parameters estimated without the interaction. So what we are going to do is add a regressor variable of known data to the model without interaction, and $\lambda$ it´s going to be it´s regression coefficient. This was actually proposed by Tukey a bunch of years ago as the one degree of freedom test for non-additivity (interaction).